# How to prevent hanging of application when a button is clicked multiple times?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application where user can click on a Scan button to scan the image to preview in the application. When user clicks, usually a "Preparing to scan" message will be shown and goes away when the scan is 100% complete.

The scan works fine. The problem if I stress test it by pressing the scan button many times while it's doing it's work, the application completely hangs and the message just stays there and I had to restart my whole application.

The code: It's just a small section

```
private void ScanStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SCAN_INTO_BATCH)
    {
        GENERATE_BATCH_FOLDER = true;
        StartTwainScan();
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to prevent this issue? 
Appreciate the help

EDIT:

```
public void StartTwainScan()
{
    Boolean EnableUI = false;
    Boolean ADF = false;
    Boolean EnableDuplex = false;

    if (Properties.Settings.Default.TwainShow.Equals("1"))
    {
        EnableUI = true;
    }

    if (Properties.Settings.Default.ScanType.Equals("2"))
    {
        ADF = true;
    }

    if (Properties.Settings.Default.DuplexEnable.Equals("1"))
    {
        EnableDuplex = true;
    }

    var rs = new ResolutionSettings
    {
        Dpi = GetResolution(),
        ColourSetting = GetColorType()
    };

    var pg = new PageSettings()
    {
        Size = GetPageSize()
    };


    var settings = new ScanSettings
    {
        UseDocumentFeeder = ADF,
        ShowTwainUI = EnableUI,
        ShowProgressIndicatorUI = true,
        UseDuplex = EnableDuplex,
        Resolution = rs,
        Page = pg
    };

    try
    {
        TwainHandler.StartScanning(settings);
    }
    catch (TwainException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        //Enabled = true;
        //BringToFront();
    }
}
```

Comment: wrap into async await. or prevent from multi click

Comment: @Z.R.T. Can you clarify more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't going to be the correct answer, but you haven't shown enough code to give you the right code. It should point you in the right direction.

```
private void ScanStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScanStripButton.Enabled = false;
    if (SCAN_INTO_BATCH)
    {
        GENERATE_BATCH_FOLDER = true;
        StartTwainScan();
    }
    ScanStripButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

Basically you disable the button when the scan starts and enable it when it finishes.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to achieve. Will it a try

Comment: It works. Thank you, didn't know as simple as disabling a button and enabled it helps.

Comment: A simple answer is often the best.

Comment: @TomCold  in this code when StartTwainScan method throw exception , you button become disabled. you have to prevent this case

Comment: @Z.R.T. is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: @Z.R.T. - Your `try`/`finally` code block is bad. It swallows errors and that should be avoided. If an exception is thrown by the scan then only that exception should be caught.

Comment: so which is better?

Comment: @TomCold - My code doesn't have a lot of things. You need to provide as much real code as possible to get a full answer.

Comment: @TomCold - It would be better to enable and disable the button plus implement a specific `try`/`catch` block to handle any specific exceptions that the scanner produces.

Comment: @Z.R.T. - Your use of `private bool clicked` is also not great - you're adding in code that isn't needed which just increases the chances of coding bugs. `button.Enabled` is already there and does a better job.

Comment: @Enigmativity What if there is already a try catch in my StartTwain method. as shown in my edited post

Comment: @TomCold - Your code already handles the exception so my code would work just fine.

Comment: @Enigmativity So if the method throws an exception, what will happen to the scan button, enabled?

Comment: @TomCold - Your method handles it already so then my code just runs perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
private async void ScanStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (SCAN_INTO_BATCH)
        {
            GENERATE_BATCH_FOLDER = true;
            StartTwainScan();
        }
    });
}

or 

private bool clicked = false;
private void ScanStripButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if(clicked)
            return;

        clicked = true;
        if (SCAN_INTO_BATCH)
        {
            GENERATE_BATCH_FOLDER = true;
            StartTwainScan();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        clicked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't try your solution though because the solution marked above is much simpler but thanks though

Comment: Can you explain in detail the second solution?

Comment: The first solution is likely to run in to issues with the Twain driver using an apartment threading model. The second solution is redundant as `ScanStripButton.Enabled` can do the same thing as `private bool clicked` but it provides more user-friendly behaviour. The `try`/`finally` also swallows **all** errors - and that's bad. You should only ever catch specific exceptions.